# Custom MAM application

Tags: ios, mdm

I was wondering if its possible to code your own MAM server or application for the iOS platform. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction but I'm looking for a way to silently push out applications, either through the App Store or off of a server. The problem currently is that the solutions that I have tried require you to keep re entering your password for every application you want to install which is a pain if the user wants to update an application since they don't know the account/password. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated previously and quite a few times on stack overflow - you cannot silently push out applications on iOS as Apple does not provide support for this. Every application installation has to be approved by the user.

Comment: Than why are other companies that offer (paid) mdm solutions say their software is able to do silent app push outs? I'm doubtful that they would false advertise.

Comment: In my experience, other companies like to merge the capabilities of all the platforms they support into one list rather than separating them out into per-platform lists. This gives the impression that they can support certain features on all platforms. However, it is possible to push out web clips silently, but not native apps on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 7, you can push applications silently to supervised devices.

You can watch WWDC 2013 videos to learn more information.

Also, you can make device supervised using Apple configurator.